# How can I open this robot claw?

Tags: animation, armature

[image]

I have this "robot claw", and i want to open it simmetrically, but I cant, because blender wants to rotate it using global axises.

Edit:

After I've set the orientation to local, I still cant rotate/move the bone according to my plan.

[image]

Comment: Change your transformation orientation, at the top or bottom of your 3D viewport, from "global" to "normal", and then in pose mode, constrain your transformation, e.g. 'g x' to translate in bone's local axis.

Comment: Thank you, but I still cannot do it properly, after changing it to local orientation.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I got it, I had to recalculate the roll of all bones, then use the local axis, and individual origins.

Comment: Hi, thanks for the post. This site is not a regular forum, answers should be substantial and thoroughly explain the solution and required workflow. One liners and short tips rarely make for a good answer. If you can [edit] your post and provide some more details about the procedure and why it works. Perhaps add a few [images](https://blender.meta.stackexchange.com/questions/963) illustrating the workflow and final results. See [How do I write a good answer?](https://blender.stackexchange.com/help/how-to-answer)